# Unable to run heroku-cli commands - issues with npm

Tags: heroku, heroku-toolbelt

When trying to run `heroku fork` on Mac OS X Yosemite, I all the sudden am running into critical errors that render the CLI useless. This problem did not occur previously and I believe the CLI may have updated itself and started causing problems.

```
~ ☽  heroku fork -a oldapp newapp
Installing plugin heroku-fork... npm ERR! Darwin 14.0.0
npm ERR! argv "/Users/Me/.heroku/iojs-v2.0.0-darwin-x64/bin/iojs" "/Users/JJ/.heroku/iojs-v2.0.0-darwin-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/cli.js" "install" "heroku-fork"
npm ERR! node v2.0.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.9.0
npm ERR! code ETARGET

npm ERR! notarget No compatible version found: heroku-cli-util@'>=1.9.0 <2.0.0'
npm ERR! notarget Valid install targets:
npm ERR! notarget ["1.0.0","1.0.1","1.1.0","1.2.0","1.3.0","1.4.0","1.5.0","1.7.0","1.8.0","1.8.1"]
npm ERR! notarget
npm ERR! notarget This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
npm ERR! notarget
npm ERR! notarget It was specified as a dependency of 'heroku-fork'
npm ERR! notarget

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/Me/.heroku/npm-debug.log
ERROR: exit status 1
Usage: heroku COMMAND [--app APP] [command-specific-options]

Help topics, type "heroku help TOPIC" for more details:

  heroku version                       # print the version
  heroku plugins                       # manage plugins
  heroku update                        # update heroku-cli
```

I've tried removing and reinstalling the heroku cli via: homebrew, the official installer, even the rubygem.  Since the error seems to suggest there's an npm problem, I updated npm and all of my npm packages, and was even able to explicitly run `npm install -g heroku-cli-util@1.10.0` but none of that has made any difference.

What is going wrong here/how can I fix this?  This is a critical issue for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the cache got stuck somehow, try deleting `~/.heroku` and trying again.

EDIT: turns out this was an issue with caching on the Heroku private npm server.

Comment: I actually completely deleted `~/.heroku` before reinstalling, so don't think this was the issue

Comment: Tried reinstalling, clearing `~/.heroku/.npm-cache`, and then running `heroku fork` again--same issue

Comment: try deleting all of `~/.heroku`